# Linebreak in a longtable

Tags: line-breaking, longtable

I use the longtable package to create a table that covers multiple pages, but the problem is that the linebreake does not function correctly.This is my code:

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{{|p{0,5cm}|p{1,6cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{0,8cm}|}}\hline
Anfang & Ende & System & Netzbetreiber & Un\newline$[kV]$ & Länge\newline[km] & R\newline$[\Omega]$ & X\newline$[\Omega]$ & B\newline$[\mu$S] & I\newline[A] \\
% &  &  &  & [kV] & [km] & $[\Omega]$ & $[\Omega]$ & $[\mu$S] & [A]\\
\hline\hline
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\ N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\ N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\ 
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\ 
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\ 
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\ 
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\ 
N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

   \end{document}
```

The Linebreaks are not activted for the first, third and fourth coulmn of the firs row, even with the fixed coulmn width. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The `\newline` work fine, your units come on the next line, however TeX does not hyphenate the first word of a paragraph (and as in the example english patters are used it probably would break incorrect;y anyway) I added `\-` in some places.

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\def\zz{ N & N & N  & N   & N   & N & N  & N  & N & N \\}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0,5cm}|p{1,6cm}|*{7}{p{1cm}|}p{0,8cm}|}\hline
Anf\-ang & Ende & Sys\-tem & Netz\-bet\-rei\-ber & Un\newline$[kV]$ & Länge\newline[km] & 
R\newline$[\Omega]$ & X\newline$[\Omega]$ & B\newline$[\mu$S] & I\newline[A] \\
% &  &  &  & [kV] & [km] & $[\Omega]$ & $[\Omega]$ & $[\mu$S] & [A]\\
\hline\hline
\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz
\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz
\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz
\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz
\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz
\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz
\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz\zz
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Manually I can achieve the required result but I wnated to achieve this automatically. I used as well follwing pacakge for the language:
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

Comment: @user97388 the first word will hyphenate if you  also use `\usepackage{array}` and then replace `p{..}` by `>{\hspace*{0pt}}p{..}`

Comment: @ David Carlisle thank you so much. This works now as I wanted!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `\\` instead of `\` whenever you want to move to the next row in the table. For the first four columns, you should specify the width as `p{1,5cm}`, and for others, `p{1cm}`. The fourth column heading may be split into two.

For example, enter `Netzbe\newline{treiber}` and execute the code. This should give you the desired result.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. The supplied example does already use `\\ ` to end the table rows.