# How to force break a line to new page in longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable

I am using `longtable` and I'd like to force add a line break so that the row starting with `Others & Figuring out what one is good at....` can be on page 96 in the screenshot below.

[image]

I have searched on StackExchange for answers including [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369559/how-to-force-new-page-if-paragraph-will-break), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/line-breaking-in-longtable), and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290877/linebreak-in-a-longtable). But none of them worked or are relevant to solve what I'd like to do.

Thank you in advanced for your answers!

Comment: Could you post a MWE, please?

Comment: [How to convince longtable to do a page break earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358435/134144) might be related.

Comment: Thank you mods for suggesting a possible duplicate. `\pagebreak` works for my case.